# How to get the screen resolution of the host system in UWP app

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, screen-resolution

I am able to get the screen resolution in UWP based on the where app getting launched on some specific monitor. I have a host system and two extra displays are attached, I need to show the screen resolution of the host system. Using the below API i can get the screen resolution where app has been launched ->
`ApplicationView currentView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();`, Is there any where i can get list of all the displays and iterate and get the screen resolution of the needed display or any other workaround for this. I also know if i move the app from other display to host display i will start getting the resolution of host system but i need to show this resolution on the start app no matter where it is getting launched.

TIA

Comment: There is no such way to do that.

Comment: Does my solution meet your requirement?

Comment: I tried with .net screen class, but issue over there i need make configuration dpiaware to true in app manifest otherwise it was giving correct resolution for other monitors but not the primary monitor.
Could you upvote the question, so that i can able to start upvoting other answer and provide my solutions.

Comment: @RiteshKumar Sure. You could post your own solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any where i can get list of all the displays and iterate and get the screen resolution of the needed display or any other workaround for this.

Currently, there is no such API in UWP that could get the resolution value for all the monitors. But you could get the native device resolution of the monitors via UWP API - [DisplayMonitor Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.displaymonitor?view=winrt-22621).

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
 var selector = DisplayMonitor.GetDeviceSelector();

        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            var monitor = await DisplayMonitor.FromInterfaceIdAsync(device.Id);
            var monitorSize = monitor.NativeResolutionInRawPixels;
        }
```

Please note that, the `monitorSize` is the native resolution for the monitor. It **does not** return the resolution value you set in the Windows Settings.  For example, my second monitor's native resolution is 1920 * 1080, but I set the resolution to 1280 * 1024. The value for `monitorSize` is 1920 * 1080.

If this does not meet your requirement, you might need to look for some Win32 API or  .Net API to do this.